# Haskell getting value of Either from Get monad

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I am a Haskell noob feeling stuck on a rather simple function I am attempting to perform.  Ultimately my goal is to read a strict `ByteString`, use the `Get` monad with a decoder to retrieve the first `Word32` from the `ByteString`, and perform specific functions where `Data.Bits.testBit` evaluates to True on various parts of the `Word32`.

Here is my example code:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char
import Data.Function
import System.Random
import Data.Bits
import Data.Either
import Data.Binary.Strict.Get
import System.IO as SIO
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Data.Word (Word32)
import Data.ByteString.UTF8 as BU

dateTemplate = "YYMMDDhhmmss"

convertFromString :: String -> ByteString
convertFromString s = BU.fromString s

mahDecoder :: Get Word32
mahDecoder = do
  first32Bits <- getWord32be
  return first32Bits

main :: IO ()
main = do 
  let a = runGet mahDecoder (convertFromString dateTemplate)
  SIO.putStrLn $ show a

  -- When I uncomment these lines I get the problem

  --case a of
  --  Left val -> SIO.putStrLn "Communist!"
  --  Right val -> SIO.putStrLn $ "Fascist!"
```

When I run the `runGet` function on the decoder and pass my `ByteString` in main, I can see it returns an Either instance like so:

`(Right 1499024717,"DDhhmmss")`

When I attempt to case on Left or Right then it fails with the following error:

```
HSStackOverflowExamp.hs:31:5:
    Couldn't match expected type `(Either String Word32, ByteString)'
                with actual type `Either t0 t1'
    In the pattern: Left val
    In a case alternative: Left val -> SIO.putStrLn "Communist!"
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      case a of {
        Left val -> SIO.putStrLn "Communist!"
        Right val -> SIO.putStrLn $ "Fascist!" }
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?  I get the feeling like I am supposed to read all bytes from the ByteString with the decoder.  To be honest I am not entirely sure what the type of `a` is here.  I still have a very limited understanding of Monads and Monad Transformers.  I was hoping that I didn't need to master every one of the Haskell dark arts before I could implement even simple use cases for practice.  If the answer is to keep reading then I accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `a` is a tuple where the first item is an `Either`. Try changing your case statement to this:

```hs
case a of
    (Left val, _) -> SIO.putStrLn "Communist!"
    (Right val, _) -> SIO.putStrLn $ "Fascist!"
```

Comment: Oh wow, I mentally filtered out the parentheses.  Why does it return a tuple of one item though?  It can only Either be Left or Right and never both?  Seems very unintuitive.

Comment: There are two items in the tuple. The second one is a `ByteString` but I ignored it using the underscore in my answer.

Comment: Oh I get it now!  Right contains the tuple, with the decoded Word32 and the rest of the ByteString that I don't care about.  Thank you!